# R: gridExtra - How to plot a Summary as table?

Tags: r, gridextra

I'm having trouble plotting a simple summary.

`library(gridExtra)`
`SummaryTable <- summary(s.tvs$precio.nuevo)`
`grid.table(SummaryTable)`

Gives me this:

[image]

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: `grid.table(t(summary(mtcars$mpg)))`

Comment: Works. Please make a complete answer and explain the use of t() in this situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade comment:

`grid.table` calls `tableGrob`.

```
grid.table
#function (...) 
#grid.draw(tableGrob(...))
#<environment: namespace:gridExtra>
```

From `?tableGrob` its first argument is a matrix or data.frame. `t` coerces the named vector returned by `summary` to a matrix with dimension one row. Alternatively, you could of used `as.matrix` to produce a matrix with one column.

```
grid.newpage()
grid.table(t(summary(mtcars$mpg)))
```

[image]

```
grid.newpage()
grid.table(as.matrix(summary(mtcars$mpg)))
```

[image]

From comment:

Question: 
I'm trying to plot a barplot and the table generated in this answer. I get: `Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1, : only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"` when using this code: `grid.arrange(a, tbl, ncol = 1)`

To combine different tables / plots using `grid.arrange` they need to be grobs (grid GRaphcal OBjects). So you cannot pass the results from `grid.table` to `grid.arrange` as it is not a grob (it actually plots the `tableGrob` directly). For this you need to pass the `tableGrob`.

So for example:

```
mybar <- qplot(mtcars$mpg, geom="bar")
tbl <- tableGrob(t(summary(mtcars$mpg)))
grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(mybar, tbl)
```

Comment: I'm trying to plot a barplot and the table generated in this answer. I get: `Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"` when using this code: `grid.arrange(a, tbl, ncol = 1)`... has to do something with the transformation?

Comment: What is `a` (barplot produced how perhaps?), and i assume `tbl` is your `grid.table`. Try passing the tableGrob, rather than using `grid.table` (So for example, `grid.arrange(qplot(mtcars$mpg, geom="bar"), tableGrob(t(summary(mtcars$mpg))))`

Comment: look at the difference of `class(grid.table(t(summary(mtcars$mpg)))) ; class(tableGrob(t(summary(mtcars$mpg))))`

Comment: Until now, using class() only gave me one string: "data frame", "vector" etc. `class(tableGrob(t(summary(mtcars$mpg))))` gives me: "gtable" "grob"   "gDesc"... what those mean?

Comment: Also: passing `tableGrob` instead of: t() worked. Please update your answer with an explanation for all of this comments.