# Adding a statistics table to the bottom of a ggplot, geom_bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to create a plot that has a barchart of coefficients in the top 7/8 of the plot, and a table with statistics in the bottom 1/8. After creating the plot, I save it to a pdf file, which I've been doing with ggsave() and would like to keep that functionality.  The program was originally built for just the barcharts, and I am adding in the statistics table.

I am at a loss on how to make this happen, or if I'm even thinking of it the right way.

Initially, I attempted:

```
  tablestats <- grid.table(stats, rows = NULL)
  grid.arrange(plt, tablestats, nrow = 2)
```

But I can't have a non grob in the above function.

Then I tried:

```
  layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE))
  plt <- plt + tablestats
  print(plt)
```

But this only plots the barchart.

I've also tried the par(mfrow()) method, but it seemingly ignores the table when plotting.

Does anyone have any advice on how to build something like this or similar?
[image: Ideal plot layout]

Comment: Hi S, could you maybe sketch out what you would like the plot/annotations to look like with pen/paper, and post the image? I think I know what you are looking for in general, but would like to confirm. Thanks :)

Comment: Of course! I did one better and put some pictures together

Comment: https://magesblog.com/post/2015-04-14-plotting-tables-alsongside-charts-in-r/

Comment: @Tung you are my hero. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you have to use `tableGrob()` to define *tablestats* and not `grid.table()`.

As stated in [R: gridExtra - How to plot a Summary as table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926718/r-gridextra-how-to-plot-a-summary-as-table) :

> To combine different tables / plots using grid.arrange they need to
>   be grobs (grid GRaphcal OBjects). So you cannot pass the results from
>   grid.table to grid.arrange as it is not a grob (it actually plots the
>   tableGrob directly). For this you need to pass the tableGrob.

After that you can use `grid.arrange()` as you did.

Comment: Thank you! I misinterpreted the error message and assumed that the plt was the issue. Adding that one line in fixed it, thank you.